# Как отследить положение курсора мыши относительно нажатого места?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на элемент нужно начать отслеживать положение курсора мыши, то место в котором нажали, должно иметь координаты 0; 0.
Нашел способ отследить положение курсора относительно экрана, но относительно нажатого места не знаю как сделать.
Желательно на основе моего кода показать, так как свое уже привычно и понятно))

```js
position = false;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
  position = true;
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  position = false;
})
document.onmousemove = mousemove;

function mousemove(event) {
  if (position) {
    mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
      mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
      mouse_y = event.clientY;
    }
    console.log('x=' + mouse_x + '; ' + 'y=' + mouse_y);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Нажми и держи</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
position = false;
startx = 0;
starty = 0;
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
  position = true;
  startx = event.clientX;
  starty = event.clientY;
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  position = false;
})
document.onmousemove = mousemove;

function mousemove(event) {
  if (position) {
    mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
      mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
      mouse_y = event.clientY;
    }
    console.log('x=' + (mouse_x - startx) + '; ' + 'y=' + (mouse_y - starty));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Нажми и держи</h1>
```